# Validation for an Excel file

Tags: excel, xsd

Perhaps this is a dumb question, but I was wondering if there's any standard for having Excel validation across files? What I mean by that is something like:

- XSD for XML: https://www.w3.org/XML/Schema
- JSON Schema: https://json-schema.org/implementations.html
- CSV Schema: https://digital-preservation.github.io/csv-schema/csv-schema-1.1.html
- Excel: ??

Or is the solution for this usually "Export it to `<this_format>` and validate it using those tools?" How this this usually done, or it's not?

Answer (score 0):

Excel is a proprietary tool with its own data format. It can export a spreadsheet/worksheet (not the same thing) into various other formats.

For data interchange, the most common Excel import/export format is CSV. There is a standard for CSV but it does not specify any validation of the field names or types. If you want that, you will need something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Format_Description_Language.